# Create user table in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to create a simple table with username and passwords in influxdb.
However I am unable to do so since a tag is always required for creating a table.I want to create a table with username and password as field keys.
The query that I wrote is:

```
insert users,password value=password,admin value=admin

Error: missing tag value
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are optional.

Your query shoul be:

```
insert tablename password="yourpasswordvalue",user="yourusername"
```

As specified by Line Protocol https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/

to verify

```
> select * from tablename
name: tablename
time                password          user
----                --------          ----
1552757801383612800 yourpasswordvalue yourusername
```